# Source map in Google Chrome not working correctly

Tags: google-chrome, sass, sublimetext3, source-maps

Im using SCSS preprocessor (Sass, Compass => SCSS style) with Sublime Text 3 and build system to create css file, it also generates *.map (source-map with original destination of all scss files).

I see too strange behavior.

See screenshot:

[image]

(for example: element header and his location is in other file then google chrome showing).

Sometimes google chrome shows up the correct location, see

[image]

,but mostly bad.

Source map is [`here`](https://pastebin.com/NAvRbSMD)

Any help?

Comment: just delete the *.map file and re-compile.

Comment: not working , this was a first thing i tried.

Comment: Ever figure out what was wrong here? having a similar issue